# Package name cannot be resolved?

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

I am new to Gradle, I was trying to create a Gradle plugin, I followed all the instructions I found, but got this error at the end, I don't understand why part of the package name cannot be resolved.

And somehow it has become like this now. I'm really confused and don't know what to do, can anyone please explain why? How can I solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF18u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio project `File->Close Project`

then go to project directory in `AndroidStudioProjects` folder then find `.gradle` folder and just delete it.

Now reopen AndroidStudio and open Project . This may help

Comment: I'm using mac and only found a folder named "gradle", which consists of wrapper, didnt find the ".gradle" folder, do you mean the "gradle" folder? and if I may ask why that happened?

Comment: I tried delete the "gradle" folder but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this one, package name changed successful and app working fine. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried your method yet, but do you know why that happened? becasue now it seemed that even Project and gradle cannot be resolved

Comment: just do clear project and then rebuild project, then do this steps, maybe it working

Comment: project name must contain three fields like (com.stack.overflow) after that only file name.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when code is copied including the package name from any other place.
Make sure, you are using package name of your own project.
Else, go for Clean and rebuild.

Comment: I wrote all the code myself, and I actually cleaned and rebuilt the project but it's still there. In the instruction I followed it told me to create a package under "groovy" directory with whatever name you'd like to use.

Comment: actually the first time I successfully uploaded the plugin to local maven however when I tried to add the plugin to app gradle the problem occurred

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem, you cannot use word "android" for your project name. Create a new project and select any other name.

Comment: what？ I didn't use android as my project name.